# Using Netty as a basic transparent HTTP proxy

Tags: netty

I have a requirement to implement a service which acts as a transparent HTTP proxy, it needs to do the following:

1. Receive an HTTP request (TLS will already have been terminated so we're talking just plain HTTP here)
2. Add a header to the request
3. Forward the modified request to its intended destination in a non-blocking fashion
4. Stash/ hang on to the request for later use
5. When the response comes back, return it to the caller.
6. Package up the response and the request (stashed in #4) and send them off to another system in a non-blocking fashion.

Having read the Netty docs I have managed to put something very primitive together which accepts an HTTP request from a client and returns an HTTP response, this makes use of the following Netty components in a single server pipeline:

- HttpServerCodec
- HttpObjectAggregator
- A handler I've written, which extends `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter`, which looks like this:

  ````
  void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final Object msg) throws Exception {
      try {
          FullHttpRequest httpRequest = (FullHttpRequest) msg
          ensureAuditingHeaderIsPresent(httpRequest)
          ctx.writeAndFlush(new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.OK))
          println("Response written...")
      }
      finally {
          ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg)
      }
  }```
  ````

This all works as I'd expect, resulting in a 200 response being returned to the client (albeit an empty one). However I'm struggling to understand what sort of approach I might take to now implement the forwarding on of the HTTP request and the returning of the response to the client.

My initial thoughts were to use an async HTTP client library, but I get the feeling I'm missing something built in to Netty which would allow me to do this in a pipeline? Perhaps some sort of outbound `ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter`?

As you can tell my current understanding of the Netty internals is very basic, so grateful for any pointers!

Final question: Is the 2015 netty-in-action book still worth a read? I'm loathe to buy it if it's going to be totally out of date, but it it's still relevant then might be worth a read?

Many thanks,

Edd

Answer (score 1):

You'll need two pipelines - one for the server side (aka incoming channel), and one for the client side (aka outgoing channel) towards the target server. Once you receive a request, from the incoming channel's handler, you'll want to kick off a new connection to the target server and pass a) the HTTP request (modified as necessary) and b) a reference to the incoming channel context. Once you receive the response from the target server, from your outgoing channel handler, you can simply write back the response (modified as necessary) to the incoming channel. No external libraries necessary.

A (much simplified) pseudo-code sample to point you in the right direction:

Your server side handler would look something like:

```
void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final Object msg) throws Exception {
    try {
        FullHttpRequest httpRequest = (FullHttpRequest) msg;
        ensureAuditingHeaderIsPresent(httpRequest);
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(eventLoopGroup) // use the same eventLoopGroup as the server's
                .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(new HttpClientCodec())
                                     .addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator())
                                     .addLast(new MyProxyOutgoingChannelHandler(httpRequest.copy(), ctx));
                    }
                });
        String targetHost = getTargetHostFromRequest(httpRequest);
        int targetPort = getTargetPortFromRequest(httpRequest);
        b.connect(targetHost, targetPort);
    }
    finally {
        ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);
    }
}
```

Your outgoing channel handler would then look like:

```
class MyProxyOutgoingChannelHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler {

    private final ChannelHandlerContext incomingChannelCtx;
    private final HttpRequest httpRequest;

    void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final Object msg) throws Exception {
        FullHttpResponse response = (FullHttpResponse) msg;
        incomingChannelCtx.writeAndFlush(response);
    }

    @Override
    void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        ctx.write(httpRequest);
    }
```

Re: Netty In Action, I haven't read it myself, but the author Norman Maurer is the still the project lead, and I have no doubt that the concepts in the book are still relevant even if the code samples may be outdated.

Hope that helps.